# opening a file in c++ using a variable

Tags: c++, file, file-io

Need help opening a file using infile.open() using a variable and string combo,

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("data_x.txt");
```

I need something like this but the X in data_X.txt must be a variable that can be changed.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 3):

with C++ you can use a string stream

```
std::ostringstream file_name;
file_name << "data_" << somevar;

infile.open(file_name.str());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly. Do you need to open a file named "something_X.txt", but with possibility of replacing 'X' with value of some variable? If so:

```
template <typename T>
ifstream read_file(const char* baseName, const T& value, const char* extension)
{
  std::ostringstream file_path;          // Here we will assemble our name
  file_path<<baseName<<value<<extension; // Add baseName, value and extension.

  ifstream file_handle(file_path.str()); // Open the file.
  if(!file_handle)
  {
    //This file doesn't exist! Notify user in some way.
  }

  return file_handle; // Return handle to file we have opened.
}
```

Now you can do:

```
file_1 = read_file("data_", 5, ".txt"); //Opens "data_5.txt"
file_2 = read_file("personal", "info", ".ini"); //Opens "personalinfo.ini"
```

I provided a more general solution, so you can customize constant-prefix of name ("data_" in your specific case) and extension of file. Example: this loop will open "texture_1.jpg", "texture_2.jpg", ..., "texture_10.jpg".

```
const char* base_name = "texture_";
const char* extension = ".png";
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
  ifstream tex_file = read_file(base_name , i, extension);
  //read data from this file
  tex_file.close();
}
```

Since function is templated, you can use variable of any type T, for which there is a valid operator<<(ostringstream&, const T&) - all built-in types satisfy this requirement. Go here for details: [cplusplus.com: operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator<</).

Comment: You're 2nd example of usage is wrong it opens "personalinfo.ini", the function doesn't add the underscore...

Comment: 'You're 2nd example of usage is wrong' -> it's not. It's perfectly valid code and will open file if such exists. If anything is wrong, it's the comment. This is something we usually call 'typo error'. Fixed.

Comment: My mistake, there was a typo in the comment. 8-)